# Add target for UIButton - iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

Anyoone can help me on how to add action to call the following method using `UIButton`.

```
-(void)navigatePics:(id)sender andIndex:(NSInteger *)index{}
```

Comment: Please explain what type of functionality you want.  Do you want someone to write between the {}'s to make the method do something?  Or do you need help hooking it up to the Interface Builder (IB)?

Comment: I just looking for the [button addTarget:self action:@selector(_this space____) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the button.setTag:(NSInteger) method to add the index to the UIButton as a tag.

```
UIButton *button = ...;
[button setTag:1234];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatePics:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in navigatePics, read the tag.

```
-(void)navigatePics:(UIButton *)sender
{
 int index = sender.tag;
 // index = 1234;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button.tag = 4; //index
[button addTarget:self @selected(buttonDidTap:)];

...
[button release];

-(void)buttonDidTap:(UIButton *)sender{
NSInteger index = sender.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Don't use self if you want to call this method on another instance. In that case, just use that instance in place of self.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatePics:andIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: how would i pass the index value?

Comment: you can't pass the index value... get it from the sender